# Locating Table Element by xPath in Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I copied the xPath of a certain element I am trying to click and obtained the following:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_body_homebody_PageMainContent_ResultsGrid_ctl00__0"]/td[1]/a
```

My code then contains the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_body_homebody_PageMainContent_ResultsGrid_ctl00__0"]/td[1]/a").click()
```

Any idea why I might be getting this error: r
aise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: `"//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_body_homebody_PageMainContent_ResultsGrid_ctl00__0"]/td[1]/a"` is not a valid string in Python, try:

   `'''//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_body_homebody_PageMainContent_ResultsGrid_ctl00__0"]/td[1]/a'''`

Comment: It still can't locate the element. Is something wrong with using the //* instead of //table? I tried both but I feel like it may be an error there

Comment: That's an XPATH - use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_id`

Comment: Right! Thank you so much. Got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPATHs may contain `id` (or many other HTML tags), but that does not mean that the `id` *is* the XPATH.  Use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_body_homebody_PageMainContent_ResultsGrid_ctl00__0"]/td[1]/a').click()
```

and it should work - assuming there is a valid XPATH at that location on your website.

also, re: your comment on the OP - `//*` specifies relative XPATH vs absolute XPATH - essentially meaning that it skips the initial  and  tags and goes straight to the middle of the DOM.